# Application error when access /_layouts/15/clientname.FBAProject.FBA2FA/Login.aspx,

Tags: 2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 FBA web application, that was normally working, and suddenly in the login page I am getting 403 Access Denied

WHen I check the ULS logs I found this:

1. The application poool is under an account sp_dev_farm which has access to both folders on the first line of the error.
2. The applicaiton pool account also has permission on SQL Server, but I dont think it has anything to do with this.

   Application error when access /_layouts/15/xxx.FBAProject.FBA2FA/Login.aspx, Error=Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\TwoFactorDllo80\bin' is denied.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()

    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
    at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
    at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
    at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_DefaultAjaxFrameworkAssembly()
    at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager..ctor()
    at ASP._layouts_15_errorv15_master.__BuildControlScriptManager() in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\errorv15.master:line 25
    at ASP._layouts_15_errorv15_master.__BuildControl__control19() in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\errorv15.master:line 24
    at ASP._layouts_15_errorv15_master.__BuildControl__control3() in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\errorv15.master:line 6
    at ASP._layouts_15_errorv15_master.__BuildControlTree(_layouts_15_errorv15_master __ctrl) in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\errorv15.master:line 1
    at ASP._layouts_15_errorv15_master.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6e7557e4\b1dd58aa\App_Web_errorv15.master.9c9699a8.qjxveg5g.0.cs:line 0
    at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Please verify that if bin folder of your wep-application is having permisson for the User.

Comment: for what user?  It has permission for the application pool user, but do you mean another specific user?

Comment: Every user need to have read access to the folder "bin" of application.

Comment: You can check by right clicking the bin folder -->Click security tab you will see the list of user

Comment: thanks a lot,  struggled with this for a few hours, now its fixed.